# How to combine view transitions from multiple threads?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading

I have an Obj-C iPhone app with 2 threads. The first thread of course contains the GUI. The second thread does a lot of work and at some point runs a method on the main thread which displays a modal UIViewController. I would like this UIVC to appear animated, but at that moment the GUI may be in a state of dismissing a UIVC (because the user may just be navigating through the app), in which case I get an

```
Uncaught exception: Attempting to begin a modal transition from <UINavigationController: 0x180dbb20> to <UINavigationController: 0x17f3c810> while a transition is already in progress. Wait for viewDidAppear/viewDidDisappear to know the current transition has completed
```

What is the correct way to deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animations are all run on mainThread

You can try to delay present animation or set push animation to `NO`

in

```
-viewDidAppear {
    double delayInSeconds = 0.1;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [self present];
    });
```

Comment: I'd rather not present the new VC without animation, because although the user expect it to appear at some moment, it does interfere with his usage of the app, so it should appear gracefully. Your solution worked fine, thanks.